# Do I need to re-init Loader every time a Fragment is being attached?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I realized that if the `Loader` is already initialized in a `Fragment` and the same `Fragment` is already added to the `FragmentManager`, the `Loader` `onLoadFinished` method is called every time the fragment is attached even if I don't explicity call `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this)`.

Does this mean that once a `Loader`has been initialized I don't really need to init it again unless the `Fragment` is recreated?